# Ruby on rails: Call create object function from angular.js app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have a rails app which works as an api, here my controller:

```
class CarController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @car = Car.new(params[:car])
    if @car.save
      render json: @car, status: :created, location: @car
    else
      render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

I want to "call" this **create** function from my angular app, here my angular factory

```
angular_app.factory('api', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    return {
   //car looks like {owner:'Andres', year:'2014', ....} with every field of Car model
            SaveCar: function(car) {
                return $http.post('/car/', {car:car}).then(function(result) {
                    return result;
                })
            }
        }
});
```

The problem is that in my create car function I get someting like this:

```
{"{\"car\":{\"owner\":\"andres\",\"year\":\"2014\",....}}"=>nil, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"car"}
```

just an string, and it should be:

```
{"car" => {"owner"=>"andres", "year":"2014", ....}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"task"}
```

What is my mistake here? I tried to use `JSON.parse` but didn't work.

Comment: Maybe problem in strong parameters. So instead of `params[:car]` use `params.require(:car).permit!`. But it throw another error in this case. All seems ok. Except there is no routes for this request.

Comment: @zishe tried that and got `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: car):`

Comment: Perhaps that `car` in angular part is a string, not object. log it.

Comment: string? I created as follow: `var car = {owner:"Andres", year:"2014", ....}`

Comment: Then it's fine. So your routes is pretty ordinary?

Comment: @zishe just `resources :car`. By the way, it could be an stupid mistake, I started to learn rails yesterday.

Comment: @zishe got it, thanks for your help, if you find a better approach just answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
def create
    @car = Car.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read)['car'])

    if @car.save
        render json: @car, status: :created, location: @car
    else
        render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

It works, but I don't really know what `request.body.read` does. Feel free to edit it and explain(remember, I'm starting with ruby)